# Asynchronous socket hangs intermittently on Unity-iOS

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, tcp

I'm currently working on a Network Controller script, which uses C# Socket class to communicate with a dedicated server.

It makes use of asynchronous callback methods so that it sends/receives data asynchronously and processes them accordingly.

Most of the time, it works perfectly cross-platform (iOS and Android).

However, sometimes the socket would silently "hang" without any explicit error, neither sending nor receiving any more data from server. (In my testing it always happened on an iOS client.)

I double-checked just to be sure it's not a problem on the server side.

Interestingly, the server sees the socket connection with the affected client still alive, and force-quitting the client still causes it to disconnect. It's just calls to send/recv that fails.

Other, unaffected devices continue to send and receive data just fine.

The only way to recover from this is to forcefully close and reopen socket, which is impractical given that no Exception seems to be raised when this happens. (I once had "InvalidOperationException: No operation in progress" on a call to SendAsync which I am now handling -- but why is this happening anyway?)

What could be the cause?

Here are some of the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class NetworkController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static NetworkController instance;

    private Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    private byte[] _receiveBuffer = new byte[8142];

    private List<byte> _inBuffer;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (!instance)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void Connect()
    {

        _inBuffer = new List<byte>();

        SetupServer();
    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {

        _clientSocket.Disconnect(true);
        _inBuffer = null;
    }

    IEnumerator Reconnect()
    {
        Disconnect();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Connect();
    }

    private void SetupServer()
    {
        try
        {
            _clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), PORT));
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);

            StartCoroutine(Reconnect());
        }

        _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);

    }

    private void CheckForMessages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_inBuffer.Count < sizeof(int))
            {
                return;
            }

            int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(_inBuffer.ToArray(), 0);
            msgLength = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(msgLength);
            if (_inBuffer.Count < msgLength + 4)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] message = _inBuffer.GetRange(4, msgLength).ToArray();
            ProcessMessage(message);

            int amtRemaining = _inBuffer.Count - msgLength - sizeof(int);
            if (amtRemaining == 0)
            {
                _inBuffer = new List<byte>();
            }
            else
            {
                _inBuffer = _inBuffer.GetRange(msgLength + 4, amtRemaining);
            }

        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            int received = _clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);

            if (received <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Reconnect());
                return;
            }

            byte[] recData = new byte[received];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_receiveBuffer, 0, recData, 0, received);

            _inBuffer.AddRange(recData);
            CheckForMessages();

            _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reconnect());
        }
    }

    private void SendData(byte[] data)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketAsyncData = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketAsyncData.SetBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);
        try
        {
            _clientSocket.SendAsync(socketAsyncData);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reconnect());
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

[Here](https://pastebin.com/DG20baLP)'s a full packet log before the socket hangs at time `62.838564` (making a link due to large size).

Comment: You can check status of connection from cmd.exe >Netstat -a after the failure to see if the connection has errors.  You can also use a sniffer to help determine where/when it is failing.  Check with sniffer if you see [FIN] which indicates the connection closed.

Comment: @jdweng I've done few more tests with Wireshark attached to the iPhone device, but I'm not seeing any [FIN] when the issue is reproduced. Here is the last entry I see before the connection fails. https://imgur.com/a/eQIxBY5 Trying to send more packets from then does not generate any more outputs, but quitting the app does result in [FIN] (which is expected).

Comment: I would like to see more of the screen.  It appears the same message (same sequence number) is being sent 3 times because it is not being ack.  I want to see if 2 repeats are occurring 5 seconds apart.  The sequence number should increment every time a message is send.  If the far end is not ack then it is busy.  Does this issue occur randomly or  starts to happen only when the connection is open for very long periods of time?  The ack should contains the sequence number of send message.

Comment: @jdweng I don't quite get it. Those were all from when the client was still actively communicating with the server, with the client successfully receiving the last ACK message from the server (`45264 -> xxxxx`). Anyways, here's another test with Wireshark view expanded. https://imgur.com/a/HCkE6no The FINs are expected as I let the phone go to sleep. When the issue occurs seems to be completely random. Sometimes it occurs as soon as the game start messages are exchanged between clients and the server, but this time it managed to get through 5 minutes of gameplay.

Comment: Also, I tried to reproduce the issue on the Android build (with the same networking code), but it never once occurred on Android.

Comment: It looks like data is only being send in one direction (10.0.1.4 to 112.184.7.251).  Everything in the other direction is the ACK which is 52 bytes (except first line).  It looks like the ACK for 361456 is missing.  There should be a retry 5 seconds later (or earlier) if there is no ACK.  Usually there are 3 retries so 361456 may be the 3rd retry.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, indeed the data were meant to be sent one-directional at that time. I forgot to save a log file for the above case, so I ran another test and have now updated the question with a full packet log.

Comment: In short, what it's doing is the client sends the player's position vector to the server, where it is then broadcast to other clients (excluding one who sent it) so that they can update the player's position.

Comment: I assume the sniffer is on the server.  I do not know if the client is directly connected to the server or through a multi-hop connection.  All I can tell is the server is not receiving any more messages from the client.  Since other client are working I do not think it is a software issue.  I suspect a hardware issue with a cable/connector.   And if it is with a router/server in a multi-hop connection it could be some place in the middle.

Comment: When a router stops working what is suppose to happen is an alternate route is used (when one is available).  The sender of a message would not get an ACK and a retry would be sent on a different route.  So if it is a problem in the middle there is no alternate route.  Since the Android is working does it have a different IP address (different subnet)?  The IP address starting with 10 is a local subnet while the IP starting with 112 is a public network.  So the issue is probably in the local subnet or the device itself. What is interesting is the 3rd line from end where the device sends a FIN.

Comment: There are three things to consider 1) There are no retries 2) The connection is still good due to the [FIN] at the end 3) It doesn't hang on Android.  This leads me to believe there is an issue between the app and the Ethernet driver on the device.  The Ethernet driver on device is still connected to the server.   So either the app hung up or there is a communication issue between app and Ethernet driver.  I would make sure device had updated Ethernet driver and the latest version of app is on device.  It is possible another application on device caused device to hang.

Comment: @jdweng The Android device was on the same subnet as the iPhone. The server is on a public IP. I also tested over a LTE network, which made no difference. For now I’ll try rewriting the sockets code using synchronous APIs w/ threads as I heard many cases where asynchronous APIs on Mono being the source of problems. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See my last comment.  Since the last three lines of the sniffer data shows the closing of the connection and the ACK of the closing the issue is not with the connection.  The connection was still good.  That leads to the conclusion that the issue is inside the IPhone.  There is no retires which indicates no messages was sent from IPhone (or the retries/ack/nack are not working on the IPhone) which again is inside the IPhone.  Does the issue occur on all IPhones?

Comment: I don't like Synchronous Methods.  They cause a lot more issues than the Asynchronous methods.  I do not know specifically the issues with Mono.

Comment: Phone is just periodically sending data not receiving.Async method usually fail on receive (not transmit).So you must have some timer that is periodically sending data.The timer is stopping.You are not loosing just one message, App is never sending any more messages.This has nothing to do with the Ethernet.The Send and Async Send are almost identical.There are two streams. One from your application to the connection (part of the app)  and one from the connection to the Ethernet interface.The connection to the Ethernet is the same.  So the Async only moves data from the App buffer to the conn.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, the issue seems to be present on at least two different iPhone models I'm currently using to test my app (XS and 6+), so I'd assume it's on all iPhones. They both have the latest version of my code, built with latest version of Unity and Xcode, on the latest OS. Here is one more discovery: I tried `Socket.BeginSend`/`EndSend` instead of `Socket.SendAsync`, and printed out log on each call to `BeginSend` and also in the async callback where `EndSend` is called. When the issue is reproduced, `Socket.BeginSend` is still being called, but the callback stops firing.

Comment: A custom callback is :   static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar){Socket handler = ar.AsyncState as Socket; int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);}  You do not need a BeginSend or an EndSend.  Make sure you are resetting the parameter in the call.  The callback will only stop if you missing a EndSend for each BeingSend.  Put into the log file after each EndSend.  Maybe you are doing two BeginSend without an EndSend.  the EndSend may be giving an exception so add an exception handle.

Comment: What about putting a lock in the callback routine to make sure each BeginSend get an EndSend.  The EndSend may not be completing before you send another message.

Comment: @jdweng OK, this may need further testing but putting a lock in the Send callback seems to have resolved the issue. I'll give enough tests just to make sure and post it in my own answer.

Comment: The operating system is slower on IPHONE than Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved the problem.

### Here's what I have done:

Use `BeginSend` instead of `SendAsync`. Put a thread lock between `BeginSend` and in the callback where you call `EndSend`, so that each `BeginSend` gets an `EndSend` before another `BeginSend`.

### Here's the code:

```
    private ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void SendData(byte[] data)
    {
        _clientSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);

        sendDone.WaitOne();
        sendDone.Reset();
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesSent = _clientSocket.EndSend(ar);

            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reconnect());
        }
    }
```